# Accessing enum variables/methods

Tags: java, enums

```
enum ChineseMenu {

    SOUP_CHICKEN(22), SOUP_VEG(32),

    NOODLES_NONVEG(23), NOODLES_VEG(55),

    RICE_NONVEG(43), RICE_VEG(66);

    private int value;

    ChineseMenu(int price) {
        this.value = price;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return value;
    }
}




class ChineseDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChineseMenu[] chineseArray = ChineseMenu.values();
        for (ChineseMenu menu : chineseArray) {
            System.out.println("The price of " + menu + " is ");//i want to add the price value
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code i want to add the prices value after "is". I even tried declaring a method and then calling the same. But it gives an error that static type cannot refer to non static variables

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking solution for -1>”In the above code i want to add the prices value after "is" “ or 2>you are getting error – “But it gives an error that static type cannot refer to non static variables”. If your problem is 1 then kocko already provided the solution. And for second one, I don’t see any problem which causes error 2.

Comment: It was 1. And it proved helpful. This enum method is a way too much powerful than I thought. Can make life easier in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above code i want to add the prices value after "is"

Judging by the above line from your question and the fact that your print statement says `The price of menu is`, it looks like you want to print the total cost of the Chinese menu :

You can create a variable called `total` that holds the total price :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChineseMenu[] chineseArray = ChineseMenu.values();
        int total = 0;
        for (ChineseMenu menu : chineseArray) {
            total+=menu.getCost();

        }
        System.out.println("The price of Chinese menu is "+total);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that he wants the total, instead of each individual item.

Comment: @ach That was my interpretation of what the OP wants as already explained in my answer. Regardless of whether the OP wants the total or not, this answer demonstrates how to call a method from an enum. (read `m.getCost()`). It's a Win-Win, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
System.out.println("The price of " + menu + " is " + menu.getCost());
```

Comment: It Worked! Thanks buddy. You've solve a big problem of mine.
:)